# What happened after I upgraded the kernel version?

Tags: linux-mint, linux-kernel, upgrade

I have Linux Mint 17.1 Cinnamon version on my notebook HP Compaq 15-h050nl and about 1 month ago I upgraded the Linux Kernels to the current version (3.18.2-031802-generic) from the last version.

After done that, I had 2 problems; firstly, when I start the laptop there appears an error message in which one informs that 1 or more cooling fan is not working. Secondly, after the first error message, it appears another message as follows:

```
[x.xxxxxx] Ignoring BGRT: invalid status 0 (expected 1)
```

Now, although the laptop works properly, it is really slow in starting and running softwares.

By running synaptic, I noted that both the old version (3.16.32) and the new version updated are installed.

Could be due to the fact I have been running 2 kernels version this problem?

To try solving the problem, I thought about to

- downgrade the Kernel version to the previous one (3.16.0-34), since with the previous version there was not problem and the laptop works pretty well for what I needed;
- Delete one of the 2 kernel versions; in such case, which one I should delete?

Are those one reasonable and valid solutions?

Alternatively, can you suggest other way to find a solution?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel update tutorial posted on the [Linux Mint Community](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1928) is like a spam/fake.

One can remove the version 3.18.2-031802-generic by running:

```
sudo apt-get remove 'linux-headers-3.18.2*' 'linux-image-3.18.2*'
```

In my particular case, everything works well now.